# Jscore function in python

Tags: python

I have to write a function called jscore, which takes two inputs S and T.

```
jscore( S, T )
```

It takes two strings, S and T and it should output the jotto score of S compared with T.
This jotto score is the number of characters in S that are shared by T. Repeated letters are counted multiple times, as long as they appear multiple times in both strings.

```
>>> jscore( 'diner', 'syrup' )  # just the 'r'
1
>>> jscore( 'geese', 'elate' )  # two 'e's are shared
2
```

I already have this code:

```
def jscore(S,T):
    score = 0
    if S=='' or T=='' :
        return 0
    elif S[0] in T:
        return score+1
    else:
        return score + jscore(S[1:],T)
```

But it keeps returning 1.
What is wrong?

Comment: Your second case means that the recursion ends on the *first* matching letter, so you can only ever get `0` or `1`. See e.g. http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html to visualise what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `return score+1` with `return score+1+jscore(S[1:],T.replace(S[0], '', 1))`:

Demo:

```
>>> def jscore(S,T):
...     score = 0
...     if S=='' or T=='' :
...         return 0
...     elif S[0] in T:
...         return score+1+jscore(S[1:],T.replace(S[0], '', 1))
...     else:
...         return score + jscore(S[1:],T)
... 
>>> jscore( 'diner', 'syrup' )
1
>>> jscore( 'geese', 'elate' )
2
>>> jscore( 'their', 'there' )
4
```

Comment: What can I leave out, @jonrsharpe?

Comment: @Panthera_Tigris `score`

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) do to this efficiently in a single line:

```
def jscore(word1, word2):
    """Calculate the jotto score of two words."""
    return sum((Counter(word1) & Counter(word2)).values())
```

In use:

```
>>> jscore('diner', 'syrup')
1
>>> jscore('geese', 'elate')
2
```